# Act on specific errors in a changeset returned by Repo.update

Tags: elixir, ecto

I want to set an assign depending on the specific error Ecto.update barfed about, what is the best way to do that? In my case the changeset returned is :

```
#Ecto.Changeset<action: :update,
 changes: %{password: "blabla",
   password_bcrypt: "$2b$12$s48wU....."},
 errors: [password_confirmation: {"password incorrect",
   [validation: :confirmation]},
  password: {"should be at least %{count} character(s)",
   [count: 8, validation: :length, min: 8]}], data: #Backend.AuthPersona<>,
 valid?: false>
```

But it can also be:

```
#Ecto.Changeset<action: :update, changes: %{email: nil},
 errors: [email: {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]}],
 data: #Backend.AuthPersona<>, valid?: false>
```

I need to set an assign depending on the error returned, so I can activate the proper tab in my form.

I tried comprehensions like this:

```
for { :email, error } <- errors, do: error
```

and I imagine I could compare the returned value to an empty list in a case  statement, but I can't get it right. Also: am I using the right approach?

Comment: You could check if a key exists using `if changeset.errors[:email] do` `if changeset.errors[:validation] do` etc. Is that what you want?

Comment: Something like `conn = if changeset.errors[:email] do assign(conn, :email_error, true) else conn`? For multiple fields maybe combined into a `cond do` because I can only activate one tab at the time. Since I'm new to this I'd also like to know the most 'Elixirly' way.

Comment: So you want to assign `_error` for every field that exists in `errors`?

Comment: Say there are two fields in `errors`: `email` and `password`. In that case I want to assign `email_error` and `password error` to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the clarification in the comment section, it seems you want to create a `#{field}_error` assign for every field that is present in the changeset's `errors`. This can be achieved with `Enum.reduce`:

```
conn = Enum.reduce(changeset.errors, conn, fn {field, _}, conn ->
  assign(conn, :"#{field}_error", true)
end)
```

If your changeset contains 3 fields, `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, the above is equivalent to this:

```
conn = assign(conn, :foo_error, true)
conn = assign(conn, :bar_error, true)
conn = assign(conn, :baz_error, true)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!